# How to fix the issue after adding the firebase plugin ( ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase ), google plus did not work in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3, firebase-notifications, google-plus-signin

I am getting data from google plus login when execute only google login.  after adding fireabase plugin (ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase) for firebase notification, google plus login did not work. I did not get any data from google login.

I have already installed plugin and npm:

```
@ionic-native/firebase": "4.20.0,
@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.20.0,
angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4,
cordova-plugin-firebase": "1.0.5,
cordova-plugin-googleplus": "7.0.1,
firebase": "4.8.0
```

Comment: Could you please post the error stack trace here. So that we can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To use google plus login, you will need other plugin.
Please try `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus`